# Eliminar un nodo en específico de una lista enlazada simple | C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo el sgte código para manejar una lista enlazada simple, en este caso necesito pedirle al usuario que digite una placa que se guarda en una cadena de caracteres y luego buscar y verificar que dicha placa coincida con alguna que esté almacenada en la lista para luego eliminar el nodo que la contiene. El problema es que aunque almacene por ejemplo la placa `"ABC-123"` y pida eliminar dicho vehículo, al buscarla, el algoritmo sigue de largo como si no existiera la placa en la lista y no elimina el nodo. Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

**Aquí defino la estructura del Nodo**

```
#define tam_placa 8
#define tam_fecha 26
struct Nodo{
    char placa[tam_placa];
    char tipo;
    char fecha[tam_fecha];
    int hora;
    int min;
    int sec;
    Nodo *next=NULL; };
```

**Los métodos para insertar y eliminar**

```
void insertar(Nodo *&lista,char p[tam_placa],char t,char f[tam_fecha],int h,int m,int s,int size){

Nodo *newNodo = new Nodo();

strcpy(newNodo->placa, p);
newNodo->tipo = t;
strcpy(newNodo->fecha, f);
newNodo->hora = h;
newNodo->min = m;
newNodo->sec = s;
newNodo->next = lista;
lista = newNodo;
size++;    }

void eliminar(Nodo *&lista,char p[tam_placa]){

if(lista!=NULL){
    Nodo *borrar;
    Nodo *anterior=NULL;
    borrar = lista;
    while(borrar!=NULL && borrar->placa!=p){
        anterior = borrar;
        borrar = borrar->next;
    }
    if(borrar==NULL){
        cout << "La placa no se encuentra registrada!\n";
    }
    else if(anterior==NULL){
        lista = lista->next;
        delete borrar;
    }
    else{
        anterior->next = borrar->next;
        delete borrar;
    }
}else{
    cout << "La lista esta vacia!\n";
} }
```

**Método Main**

```
int main(){

Nodo *lista=null;
char placa[tam_placa]="ABC-123";
char p[tam_placa]="";
char tipo='c';
char fecha[tam_fecha]="17/11/2022";
int hora=20;
int min=4;
int sec=23;
int size=0;
insertar(lista,placa,tipo,fecha,hora,min,sec,size);
cout << "Digite la placa del vehiculo a eliminar: ";
cin >> p;
eliminar(lista,p);  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
while(borrar!=NULL && borrar->placa!=p){
    anterior = borrar;
    borrar = borrar->next;
}
```

Básicamente estás comparando 2 punteros y la dirección de memoria de la placa no tiene por qué ser la misma que la de `p`.

En su lugar deberías comparar los caracteres de cada una.

Puedes hacerlo con la función de C [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). Devuelve 0 cuando son iguales.

El código se ve así:

```
// Hay una conversión implícita. Si `borrar` no es igual a
// 0 o NULL se evalúa como verdadero, sino falso. 
while(borrar && strcmp(borrar->placa, p)){
    anterior = borrar;
    borrar = borrar->next;
}
```

---

Cómo estás en C++ también podrías usar la clase [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

La ventaja es que puedes usar tantos caracteres como quieras sin preocuparte por reservar memoria, la clase lo hace por ti. Además cuenta con muchas funciones útiles, por ejemplo puedes comparar 2 `string` mediante el operador `==`.

Por ejemplo, si tu estructura lo implementara lo usarías así:

```
struct Nodo{
    string placa;
    char tipo;
    string fecha;
    int hora;
    int min;
    int sec;
    Nodo *next=NULL;
};

...

Nodo *nodo;

...

bool iguales = nodo->placa == "ABC-123";
```